# Magento Exception: Invalid backend model specified

Tags: magento

I'm using magento version 1.9. I did changes in some php files. Then I refresh cache and reindex indexes. When I refresh the page I get this error.

I tried to modify 'cache_dir' = 'tmp/' and create folder. But it didn't work.

First line error in file says:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:86:"Invalid backend model specified: ultramegamenu/category_attribute_backend_grid_columns";i:1;s:6059:"#0 /var/www/vhosts/project.es/httpdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php(346): Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Invalid backend...')
```

Someone knows what´s wrong?

Comment: Some module (ultramegamenu) is probably trying to use an updatescript to add an attribute to the backend category-grid... Doing so with a bad reference for the backend-model

Comment: Ok...but, how could I solve it? and where can I found that?